# Access VBA query Extract and name it

Tags: vba, ms-access

im currently trying to make an extract from a query in form. Extract is working but im unable to give a name to my extracted spreadsheet. The problem is that file is extracted without a name, for some reason vba wont take my text box value. Im open for any solutions, thank you!

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim FirstName As String
Dim path As String

path = CurrentProject.path & "\" & FirstName & ".xlsx"

FirstName = Forms![Form2]![Text2]

            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, _
            TableName:="3_QRY_AEGIS_LIMITS_MAX", _
            fileName:=path, _
            HasFieldNames:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: You assign path before firstname, so path would have an empty string as firstname.

Comment: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much, i felt dumb and relieved simultaneously. Again thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As @Warcupine already give you solution in comment and also you solved your problem by it, I am just posting as answer so that other fresher visitor can understand that it solved.

```
Private Sub CmdExport_Click()    
Dim FirstName As String
Dim OutputPath As String
Dim TblToExport As String

FirstName = Forms![Form2]![Text2]
OutputPath = CurrentProject.path & "\" & FirstName & ".xlsx"
TblToExport = "3_QRY_AEGIS_LIMITS_MAX"

            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, _
            TableName:=TblToExport, _
            fileName:=OutputPath, _
            HasFieldNames:=True
End Sub
```